# Remove anchor links and hyperlinks from PDF in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, hyperlink, anchor

I need to take some pages from the pdf file and make a new pdf file out of them. How can I remove anchor links and hyperlinks from PDF in Python?

I try this for every page in file

```
import PyPDF2

tmp_page = splitedFile.getPage(i)
tmp_page['/Annots'].clear()
```